# ASP NET MVC 5 Delete File From Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, file-io, asp.net-mvc-5

View Code:

```
@if (File.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/Images/Cakes/" + Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.CakeImage))))
    {
        @model TastyCakes.Models.Cakes
        <form name="deletePhoto" action="/Cakes/DeletePhoto" method="post">
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        File name of image to delete (without .jpg extension):
        <input name="photoFileName" type="text" value="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.CakeImage)" />
        <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="tiny button">
        </form>
    } else {
        <p>*File Needs to be uploaded</p>
}
```

Controller Code:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult DeletePhoto(string photoFileName)
{

    ViewBag.deleteSuccess = "false";
    var photoName = "";
        photoName = photoFileName;
    var fullPath = Server.MapPath("~/Images/Cakes/" + photoName);

        if (File.Exists(fullPath))
        {
            File.Delete(fullPath);
            ViewBag.deleteSuccess = "true";
        }
}
```

Where it says if (File.Exists) AND File.Delete,  the code has squiggly lines underneath it. So I am trying to figure out what syntax I need to get thif file deleted.

Here is a screenshot of my code in the controller:
[image]

UPPDATE: I have got the code working and created a simple code example on my blog on how I got it working and how the idea came about.
http://httpjunkie.com/2014/724/mvc-5-image-upload-delete/

Comment: OK, my filePath right now is \Images\Cakes\StrawberryCheesecake.jpg.jpg  so I should be able to get this working..

Answer (score 80, accepted):

use `Request.MapPath`

```
string fullPath = Request.MapPath("~/Images/Cakes/" + photoName);
if (System.IO.File.Exists(fullPath))
{
   System.IO.File.Delete(fullPath);
}
```

Comment: I'll post a image of what the code looks like in the controller with these changes.

Comment: OK check out the image and you will see my error in the code. Do I need to use something other than File.Exists?

Comment: try with `System.IO.File.Exists` and `System.IO.File.Delete`

Comment: right now i am adding the extension manually like  string finalpath = fullPath + ".jpg"; , but  can we get file extension from server this way:  string extension = Path.GetExtension(fullPath);

Comment: Like the simplicity!

Answer (score 7):

`File`, as you're using it, is ambiguous, hence the "squiggly line". The IDE can't resolve which you mean;

[`System.Web.Mvc.Controller.File()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460208%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

or

[`System.IO.File`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx)

Use a fully-qualified name when trying to use the File API within an MVC controller.

Comment: All squigglys have gone away, but It still is not deleting the photo.

Comment: @EricB Have you tried inspecting the generated HTML, to make sure the form is being created like you expected?

Comment: I added some session variables to help debug and figured out I was appending ".jpg" when I didnt need to giving me a path of "Whatever.jpg.jpg" I fixed it thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 7):

thanks for [@Damith's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22650756/4251431)

I created this function

```
private bool RemoveFileFromServer(string path)
{
    var fullPath = Request.MapPath(path);
    if (!System.IO.File.Exists(fullPath)) return false;

    try //Maybe error could happen like Access denied or Presses Already User used
    {
        System.IO.File.Delete(fullPath);
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    { 
        //Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
    return false;
}
```

and here is a simple use of it

```
RemoveFileFromServer("Content\img\ProfilePictures\User12.png");
```

Answer (score 2):

you can also use `HostingEnvironment.MapPath`  insted of  `Request.MapPath`
This example works fine for me:

```
private bool DeleteFile(string image1_Address="")
        {
            try {
                if (image1_Address != null && image1_Address.Length > 0)
                {
                    string fullPath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~" + image1_Address);
                    if (System.IO.File.Exists(fullPath))
                    {
                        System.IO.File.Delete(fullPath);
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }catch(Exception e)
            { }
            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `using System.IO;` at the top of your controller.

Comment: I have that. I thought the same thing, but I don't think that is part of System.IO Either way it's still showing squiggly lines in the same place.

Comment: Im gonna replace the image in a sec with one showing the error

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a controller named PlacesController. make a IHostingEnvironment object in it and initialize it.

```
private readonly TouristPlaceInformationContext _context; //database context object. not necessary for this solving current problem. but it is used for database queries.
private readonly IHostingEnvironment _he;

public PlacesController(TouristPlaceInformationContext context, IHostingEnvironment he)
    {
        _context = context;
        _he = he;
    }
```

In the following function use _he.WebRootPath to get the path till "wwwroot" folder. use _he.ContentRootPath to get path till the root folder of the project. Suppose we want to delete a file in the following path: "projectRoot/wwwroot/images/somefile.jpg".Following function will get the job done.

```
public void deleteFile(string filename){
    String filepath= Path.Combine(_he.WebRootPath,"images", filename);
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(prevFilePath))
        {
             System.IO.File.Delete(prevFilePath);

        }
}
```